# Cannot get generated express code (from OpenAPI) to catch error in query parameters

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, openapi

I’m trying to get the generated code (express.js) from isa-group/oas-tools to check the input url, but I’m having no luck. (Or am I abusing the tool?!) It seems to ignore errors in the query parameters. For example, I don’t get an error sending this url:

http://localhost:8080/acQyreXchange/acQyr-sample/1.0.0/gamer/123?limit=-3&xyz=a

I would expect it to complain about ‘limit’ being out of range (-3 < 0), and ‘xyz’ being an unknown parameter. I get an error message about wrong data in the response (which I’m expecting), but nothing about the inputs. Here's the response:

```
[
    •   {
        o   message: "Wrong data in the response. ",
        o   error: 
        [
           {
               code: "INVALID_TYPE",
               params: 
                [
                   "array",
                   "object"
                ],
               message: "Expected type array but found type object",
               path: "#/"
            }
        ],
    o   content: 
        {
           message: "This is the mockup controller for getGamer"
        }
    •   }
]
```

The debug log shows:

```
2020-09-01T14:49:11.670Z info: Requested method-url pair: get - /acQyreXchange/acQyr-sample/1.0.0/gamer/123?limit=-3&xyz=a
2020-09-01T14:49:11.671Z debug: OASValidator  -res.locals.requestedSpecPath: /gamer/{gamerId}
2020-09-01T14:49:11.673Z info: Valid parameter on request
2020-09-01T14:49:11.675Z debug: Processing at checkResponse:
...
```

The api doc shows:

```
  '/gamer/{gamerId}':
    get:
      tags:
        - admins
      summary: 'given a gamerId, returns a gamer'
      operationId: getGamer
      description: Returns a gamer
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: gamerId
          description: pass the gamerId for looking up the gamer
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - in: query
          name: skip
          description: number of records to skip for pagination
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
            minimum: 0
        - in: query
          name: limit
          description: maximum number of records to return
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
            minimum: 0
            maximum: 50
      responses:
        '200':
          description: search results matching criteria
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Gamer'
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
```

I’ve tried option:
strict: true (also tried false)
validator: true (also tried false)
customErrorHandling: true (also tried false)

Comment: I've looked at the isa-oas library code, oas-validator.js, and it will validate a parameter only if it's listed as a required parameter! I'm not sure if that's by design, or if there's any way around that (other than making all my query parameters required, which of course I cannot do). Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've come up with a fix for the problem. If the owner/dev likes it, I'll mark this 'answered'.

Comment: Can you please mention fix for this issue, I'm also having similar issue

Comment: It should have been fixed last September. See this link: https://github.com/oas-tools/oas-tools/issues/250#issuecomment-1216855725

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the code said he's put this fix in asap.